# find sum of a third column for pairs in other two columns mysql

Tags: mysql, combinations

I have two column table: ID SCORE. neither ID nor SCORE are unique. So, (stylized) example:

```
ID | SCORE
----------
 1 | 5
 1 | 6
 2 | 9
 2 | 5
 2 | 6
 3 | 5
 3 | 7
----------
```

I need to get a separate three column table where I have:

```
SCORE1 | SCORE2 | FREQUENCY
---------------------------
   5   |   6    |    2
   5   |   7    |    1
   5   |   9    |    1
   6   |   7    |    0
   6   |   9    |    0
   7   |   9    |    0
---------------------------
```

I need to find the number of IDs (FREQUENCY) that have pairs of SCORE (SCORE1 & SCORE2). Order of pairs does not matter. So (5,6) and (6,5) is the same. In my example, since a pair (5,6) is in both ID 1 and ID 2, it gets frequency of 2. A pair (5,9) is in neither of IDs, hence frequency is 0, etc.

What is the best way to get the second table from the first one with SQL?

I need SQL commands since the data I have is huge. I have tried with a small part of the data to loop through all possible combinations in R, but soon gets too expensive.

Comment: What is the source of the `SCORE2` data?

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear enough. SCORE1 and SCORE2 are just the pairs of SCORE (first table). So I have for SCORE: 5 6 ... and the pair (5,6) are then first row elements of SCORE1 and SCORE2. All row elements of SCORE1 and SCORE2 are all possible pairs of column SCORE in the first table.

Comment: What happens if there are ID 1 score 5, id 1 score 6 , id 1 score 8. Do you expect 3 columns of score?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: No. I expect 3 ROWS for SCORE1 and SCORE2: so SCORE1 would have 5 5 6 and SCORE2 would have 6 8 8 row elements

Comment: why 6 / 9 is 0? - both available on id 2

Comment: you are right. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution using a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.SCORE, t2.SCORE, SUM(t1.ID = t2.ID)
FROM test t1 JOIN test t2
WHERE t1.SCORE <> t2.SCORE AND t1.SCORE < t2.SCORE
GROUP BY t1.SCORE, t2.SCORE
ORDER BY t1.SCORE, t2.SCORE
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85e1cef7aeb3e1a6cba5e9716326c641)

Comment: *"I need SQL commands since the data I have is huge. I have tried with a small part of the data to loop through all possible combinations in R, but soon gets too expensive."* Most likely this would not [scale](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b22ab28778061267eba4d5b9d43121f) on "huge" set off data as the  `INDEX(SCORE, ID)` would should give a plan including "Using temporary; Using filesort" and "Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)"  which seams not to be very optimal..  But still + 1 for the answer as i doubt there is a better query for the question requirements